# How to show onFling is at last entry/page?

Tags: android, user-interface, graphic

When scrolling/flinging in some apps, reaching the end of the list (or other items) shows a graphical representation that you've reached the end. I'm not sure what to call this but on 5.0, it looks like a partial filled-in curve.

What is this feature called and how can I find out how to implement it?

Thanks in advance and apologies for giving such limited info. in the question.